# angular2 binding applies only after mouse movement

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm a new angular2 development and currently facing a rendering issue with my application. I use @angular@2.0.0-rc.1 for my app and router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc1 for my routing, whenever I click on the a link, the static content of the page loads immediately and the binding (dynamic content) happens only when I do some interaction with the mouse like click or hover over a link. I tried various options and still couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a project configuration issue. There should be similar questions with hints about how to fix it from several weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you include the JS files is important.
This issue happened when I didn't.

```
<script src="/lib/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/zone.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue but I am using core.min.js instead. What would be the order of files in my case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by bryanm, the order of the js files is important and the placement of those script tags also matters. In my environment with angular2.rc.4, the order was

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js">
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js">
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js">
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js">
```

It has to be placed at the end of the body tag just above loading the systemjs config script.