# Angular 2 bound values not shown until after mouse move when routing

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-router

I have a directive which adds an icon to whatever element it is added to.  When that icon is clicked, I need to call a function in whatever component contains the directive.  This function uses `router.navigate` to navigate a named-outlet to a new component.  Everything works, except that after I click the icon, the new contents of the named router outlet don't show until I move my mouse.

Here are the relevant parts of the directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[editable]',        
})
...    
@Output() doEdit = new EventEmitter<string>();
...
private emitEditMessage(){
        console.log("emitting");   <-----just so I can see that the function is called
        this.doEdit.emit(this.targetField);
}
```

Here is where I use the directive in a template:

```
<span editable (doEdit)="editField($event)">
    {{CurrentPersonInfo}}                              
</span>
```

Here is the function from my parent component that is called when the directive emits:

```
public editField(fldName :string){
    console.log("before nav");
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'task-pane': 'edit' } }]);
    console.log("after nav");
}
```

When I run and click on the icon shown by the directive, I see the expected messages in the console: "emitted", "before nav", "after nav".  But the secondary route ("name:task-pane") doesn't update with the new contents until I move the mouse.

**Update**: Just noticed this: if the content in the task pane is just a hard-coded string, then it is shown immediately.  However, if I add an interpolated binding to a property of the task pane component (e.g {{Title}} ) then any hard-coded text *before* the binding shows immediately.  The bound text and any hard-coded text after it doesn't show up until I move the mouse.

Here is the panel component:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class PersonEditPanelComponent extends BasePanel{    
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("panel ctor");
    }

    public Title: string = "Edit Person"
}
```

Here is the panel template HTML:

```
This shows immediately.

{{Title}}

This and the "Title" won't show until I move the mouse after clicking the icon
```

Finally, if I put a link on my parent component that just directly calls its `editField` function (the same one called when the directive emits), then everything works - all text (hard-coded and bound) shows immediately.

So, my questions: Is there something inherent in the routing that is causing this delay for bindings being resolved?  Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change anything.  Still the same results.

Comment: have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793490/angular2-binding-applies-only-after-mouse-movement

Comment: I just took a  look at that and tried loading the libraries and it didn't change anything.

Comment: What I don't understand is why it works when I call the navigate function from a link on the page, but not when the same function is called from a link added dynamically.

Comment: Re: order of the libraries...yes, tried in the order specified.

Comment: Could you check that you have polyyfils.js set correctly?

Comment: Could to put the router navigation inside a timeout ?

Comment: I took a different approach and got it working.  I'll post an answer in just a moment.  Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  I took a different approach to attaching the event listener and got it all working.  Here are the details:

Injected `Renderer2` via the constructor on my directive:

```
constructor(elem: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private router: Router)
{}
```

Then after the code that added the icon into the page, I attached the listener like this:

```
this.renderer.listen(this.editIcon, 'click', (evt) => {
    this.doEdit.emit(this.targetField);
});
```

Where `editIcon` is the DOM element I created and added:

```
    private editIcon = document.createElement('a');
    this.editIcon.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:18px; color:red;"></i>';
    node.appendChild(this.editIcon);
```